# How can I add spacing only between items on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As the title describes I only want spacing between items. Not before the first item or after the last. I tried using padding and removing padding programmatically at my adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method from the first and the last item.

```
if (position == 0)
    holder.itemView.setPadding(0, 0, holder.itemView.getPaddingRight(), 0);
else if (position == getItemCount() - 1)
    holder.itemView.setPadding(holder.itemView.getPaddingLeft(), 0, 0, 0);
```

But when I add or remove items, positions of the first and the last items may change. Since they are not rebinding to the view, their paddings stay the same. For example I have a list like this: `1* *2* *3`. I remove 3: `1* *2*` and insert 4, 5: `1* *2* *4 *5` (`*` indicates padding). I hope I explained it clearly.

I also tried `ItemDecoration`s, but couldn't find a dynamic way to remove the last item's decoration since I am using a dynamic list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your adapter :

```
  if(position == 0 || position == numlist.size()-1){

       // I assume the list name is numlist

         holder.asterisk.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      // I assume the item name is asterisk                                          

  }
```

Comment: As I described, I already did try to hide spacings at onBindView method, where should I use this code?

Comment: As I said in the adapter with the condition of position

Comment: I already tried this in my adapter with the condition of position. But when I add or remove items, spacing of old items stay the same. I updated my question for more detailed information.